# Check if number is prime in O(sqrt(n)) in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, primes, for-comprehension

When checking if `n` is a prime number in Scala, the most common solutions is concise one-liner which can be seen in almost all similar questions on SO

```
  def isPrime1(n: Int) = (n > 1) && ((2 until n) forall (n % _ != 0))
```

Moving on, it's simple to rewrite it to check only odd numbers

```
  def isPrime2(n: Int): Boolean = {
    if (n < 2) return false
    if (n == 2) return true
    if (n % 2 == 0) false
    else (3 until n by 2) forall (n % _ != 0)
  }
```

However, to be more efficient I would like to combine checking only odds with counting up to `sqrt(n)`, but without using `Math.sqrt`. So, as `i < sqrt(n) <==> i * i < n`, I would write C-like loop:

```
def isPrime3(n: Int): Boolean = {
    if (n < 2) return false
    if (n == 2) return true
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false
    var i = 3
    while (i * i <= n) {
      if (n % i == 0) return false
      i += 2
    }
    true
  }
```

The questions are:

1) How to achieve the last version in the first version nice Scala functional style?

2) How can I use Scala `for` to this? I thought of something similar to below, but don't know how.

```
for {
    i <- 3 until n by 2
    if i * i <= n
  } { ??? }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "without any libraries"? In your `isPrime3`, you are using 2 classes and 6 methods from a library, and in your `for` comprehension, you use at least 3 classes and 6 methods. Since you yourself have no trouble using libraries, what exactly does "without any libraries" mean?

Comment: Ok, just without calculating `sqrt` to be clear - I'd like to operate only on integers. I changed the question topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a method to verify if n is prime until `sqrt(n)` without using `sqrt`:

```
  def isPrime3(n: Int): Boolean = {
    if (n == 2) {
      true
    } else if (n < 2 || n % 2 == 0) {
      false
    } else {
      Stream.from(3, 2).takeWhile(i => i * i < n + 1).forall(i => n % i != 0)
    }
  }
```

If you want to do it until n/2, which is also a possible optimization (worse than `sqrt(n)`), you can replace the last line with:

```
 (3 to n/2 + 1 by 2).forall(i => n % i != 0)
```

If you prefer, you could also make a tail recursive version, something along these lines:

```
  import scala.annotation.tailrec

  def isPrime3(n: Int): Boolean = {
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
      true
    } else if (n < 2 || n % 2 == 0) {
      false
    } else {
      isPrime3Rec(n, 3)
    }
  }

  @tailrec
  def isPrime3Rec(n:Int, i: Int): Boolean = {
    (n % i != 0) && ((i * i > n) || isPrime3Rec(n, i + 2))
  }
```

Comment: I think most people would write range as infix: `!(3 to n/2 + 1 by 2).exists(...)` - deciphering those . and () around the range seems a bit unconvenient.

Comment: @Suma Thanks, I changed it. It's cleaner yes

Comment: n/2 is much more than sqrt(n), can you rewrite to use i * i < n?

Comment: @BartłomiejSzałach you are right of course. I added a new solution with calculates only until the sqrt

Comment: `return` is kind of bad style. I'd write `if (n % i == 0) false else if (i * i > n) true else isPrime3Rec(n, i + 3)` (with linebreaks) or even `(n % i != 0) && (i * i > n || isPrime3Rec(n, i + 3))`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I agree with returns not being good, I changed it to if/else and added brackets as I usually like them.

Comment: your isPrim3Rec is missing a condition. it can only return true or else recurse. So for example n=9 with i=3 would have (false && false)=false on the left and go to the recursion agian with i=5 and then 9%5=4, 4*4>9 and return true. You should have a first condition if(n%i ==0) false else {...}

Comment: @AssafMendelson No because it will return false immediately, note the parenthesis: `(n % i != 0) && ( ... || ...)`